# Changing source control after collection database was deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Hi I have accidently delete the TFS defaultCollection , and now I seem to be having some problem trying to move a project I had under source control in that collection to a new collection I created.

I would also like to be able to dettach this colletion from TFS but when I attempt to do that TFS just freezez and does nothing.

In Visual Studio I went to File->Source Control->Remove From Source Controll

Also opened the Change Source Control Window but I see here only a few butons one of wich is bind and when I click on it seems to bind the project to the old collection but does not give me the option to bind it to the new one.

I need a way to point VIsual Studio the the new collection.

Can anyone please give me some ideeas on what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Team -> Connect Team Foundation Serve

You can see the list of the collection. Right click the new collection and click connect. it will connect to the new collection.

Now right click your old collection and click Remove and that will remove your old collection.

Also make sure you do not have any pending check ins for the old collection.